# How to run babel.transform for react with Nashorn?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, babeljs, nashorn

I am trying to use `babel.transform` instead of `JSXTranformer` for react.

```
...
ScriptEngineManager mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine nashorn = mgr.getEngineByName("nashorn");
nashorn.eval("var process = {env:{}}"); // node-modules expect that
nashorn.eval(getScript("com/facebook/babel/jvm-npm.js"));
babel = (JSObject) nashorn.eval("require('babel');");
...
```

Babel and babel-core are installed as global node modules, and I've got an error:

> Testsuite: com.my.app.BabelTransformerTest
>   Cannot find module ./lib/api/node.js
>   Cannot load module babel-core LOAD_ERROR
>   Cannot load module babel LOAD_ERROR
>   Cannot load module babel-core LOAD_ERROR
>   Cannot load module babel LOAD_ERROR
>   Cannot find module ./lib/api/node.js
>   Cannot load module babel-core LOAD_ERROR
>   Cannot load module babel LOAD_ERROR

The `./lib/api/node.js` is there in the `C:\Users\***\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules`

I heard that it is possible to run `babel.transform` from Nashorn?

Maybe there is the way to load only certain module of babel as a JavaScript file?

Comment: Just curious, why are you using nashorn instead of regular Node.js?

Comment: It's a library. for a bigger Java project. I think so...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have got it working with [Babel Standalone](https://github.com/Daniel15/babel-standalone) in jdk1.8.0_45 with the following script:

```
FileReader babelScript = new FileReader("babel.js");
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByMimeType("text/javascript");

SimpleBindings bindings = new SimpleBindings();
engine.eval(babelScript, bindings);

bindings.put("input", "<Component />");
Object output = engine.eval("Babel.transform(input, { presets: ['react'] }).code", bindings);
System.out.println(output);
```

Which returns:

```
React.createElement(Component, null);
```

The es2015 preset works as well.

Comment: Thanks will check it soon!

Comment: And fyi, for destructuring support, add the 'stage-2' preset

Answer (score 2):

You should just load babel.js directly and then evaluate `babel.transform("...")`. There shouldn't be any need to load anything from npm or node.

But, alas, you'll have to wait for the fix to [JDK bug 8135190](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8135190) to be released, as loading babel.js fails with a "method code too large" exception.

Comment: It's a pity with the Oracle update cycle... it won't be fixed until Java 9. That's bad.

Comment: According to the bug, it's fixed in 8u72 which should be available in January 2016 according to the [OpenJDK release schedule](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk8u/releases/8u72.html).

Comment: Oh, I didn't see the "backports". Good news!